# First Order Differential Equation attempt #$2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following differential equation:

> $$\frac{dy}{dt} +2y = 3. $$

In regards to the last comment I made, I will employ a different method that is much suitable to my needs. My given equation is of the form

> $$\frac{dy}{dt} + P(t)y = f(t)$$, where $P(t)$ and $f(t)$ are continuous functions.

In my case, $P(t) = 2$ and we will use the substitution $\mu(t) = e^{\int P(t)dt}$ to yield the following:

> $$\mu(t) = e^{2 \int dt} = e^{2t}.$$

Now I put my equation in the form $\mu(t) \frac{dy}{dt} + P(t)\mu(t)y = \mu(t)f(t)$ to yield

> $$\color \red {e^{2t}} \frac{dy}{dt} + 2\color \red {e^{2t}}y = 3 \color \red {e^{2t}}.$$

Now we have that:

> $$\int \frac {d}{dt} [e^{2t}y] dt = \int 3e^{2t} dt$$
>   $$\Rightarrow e^{2t}y = \frac {3}{2}e^{2t}+C$$, where $C$ is my constant of integration.

I have a feeling that this isn't correct according to what the users told me in the comment section. Can anyone verify my second attempt at this?

Comment: You then integrate each side with respect to $t$. This method is also known as the method of integrating factor.

Comment: Hi Xpw. I checked the solution you claimed and it did check out. I will edit my post accordingly whenever I spot the mistake.

Comment: Hi Chee Han. I was having problems on *when* to integrate and I integrated the very last function $(ye^{2t})' = 3e^{2t}$, but got $y = \frac{3}{2} + C$, which is definitely not correct. Something must be wrong in my OP and I will fix it if the mistake arises.

Comment: After watching several videos and similar questions online, I will pursue a different method of solving this first order ODE. I will drastically edit my question. Note that the method I initially imposed was from our professor from lecture, but found a method much suitable for me.

Comment: You just made a small error in integrating  $e^{2t}$ w.r.t. $t$

Comment: Hmmm how about now?

Comment: Looks good...  if you want xpw's solution you can solve for y.

Comment: That's where my main problem is. I'm not sure where the substitution $v = 3 - 2y$ came from, nor do I know how he arrived to the solution Xpw claimed on his first sentence.

Comment: @JohnSmith I got $y=\frac32u + C$ by observing from the original version of the OP that $(yu)^ {\prime)= 3u$. I integrated that but made multiple mistakes, so just ignore that first sentence (in fact I'm deleting the comment), since I've posted an answer that explains the $v=3-2y$ substitution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $e^{-2t }e^{2t}=1$

So to solve for y we will need to

multiply both sides by $e^{-2t}$ which gives $ y=\frac{3}{2}+Ce^{-2t }$

Answer (score 1):

Substitution method:

$\frac{dy}{dt}+2y=3 \Longrightarrow \frac{dy}{dt}=3 - 2y$

Substituting RHS with: $v=3 - 2y$  (this yields $\frac{dv}{dt} =-2\frac{dy}{dt})$ giving

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac1{-2}\frac{dv}{dt}=v \Longrightarrow \\ 
\frac{dv}{-2v}=dt$$

Integrating gives: $-2\ln v=t + C$

Backsubstituting gives $$
-2 ln (3-2y) = t+C \Longrightarrow \\
3-2y = e^{-2(t+C)}\Longrightarrow \\
y = \frac32 - ke^{-2t}\\
$$

Comment: Hi Xpw. I did the problem using the Integration Factor and I got exactly what you got, except that the plus sign should be there instead of a minus. In other words,  I got $$y = \frac{3}{2} + ke^{-2t}.$$

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake. But since the factor could be negative the results are equivalent.

Comment: Yes both results work.